# How do I connect the location of a calendar event with the iPad maps app?

Tags: ipad, calendar, mapping

I would like to be able to either navigate from a calendar event to its location within maps, or view all upcoming events on a map. Preferably, both.

How do I connect the location of a calendar event with the iPad maps app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, (as of iOS 4), this cannot be done. The location field of an event does not recognise an address, no matter how perfectly you enter it.

**[UPDATE]** In iOS 5, the location field in any calendar event will (if properly formatted) hyperlink to the Maps app.

Comment: I'm not seeing this at all. Do you have any idea what the format for "if properly formatted" actually is? Do you have an example of an address that actually works? Where *exactly* do you see a hyperlink (For example, I'm expecting to see the location hyperlinked in the popup that shows when I tap an event in the month view)?

Comment: Well, I'm looking at iOS 6 now, but yes, a location such as "140 Sussex Street, Sydney" or "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino" appears as a hyperlink to maps.app (iPhone and iPad). Is yours an Exchange calendar?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be a perfect solution, but you could try pasting in a maps.google.com link into you calendar events.
For example:
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Infinite+Loop+1,+Cupertino,+CA,+United+States&sll=37.331693,-122.030764&sspn=0.007311,0.009871&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino,+Santa+Clara,+California+95014&ll=37.331906,-122.031262&spn=0.007311,0.009871&z=17

If you open this link on an iPad it should take you to the Maps application.

But you would have to do this manually on a computer for each event.

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps that have this featured into them. Many of them are free. I think downloading a free app with this feature would be the simplest most straight forward way to do this.

Comment: Like which ones?